# What is exact signature of System.Assign (for use in procedural expression)?

Tags: delphi

Unfortunately, exact `Assign` signature is not available in the RTL source, and my attempts to guess, like:

```
const
  Assign: procedure (var F; const FileName: string) = System.Assign;
  { or }
  Assign: function (var F; const FileName: string): Integer = System.Assign;
  { also I tried "internal" one from _AssignFile }
```

didn't yield any positive results, and compiler refuses to treat this contant expression as procedural and complains about *right-value* (`E2029 '(' expected but ';' found)`).

So, which type should I use to match Delphi RTL exactly?

Comment: For the signature see doc: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Assign

Comment: @ain overloaded ? intrinsic ? Emba's wiki is damaged in much more simple situations than this. Jsut read those three(!) declarations by your link...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Assign` is a language remnant of Delphi tracing its origins to the original Turbo Pascal syntax. Long before function overloading was added to the language syntax, long before the RTL's text file and "file of type" internal data structures were documented, there was `Assign`.

`Assign` is a simple enough procedure to use, but when you look at what it has to do you'll see that it's pretty much impossible to implement without some sort of compiler magic. `File of TFoo` creates a file type that is distinct and incompatible with `File of Integer`. And yet, both can be passed as the first parameter to `Assign`.

Today, you could probably implement `Assign` using a generic type param for the file parameter. The generic type would conform to the type of the variable passed in. That's great and all, but we needed a way to associate a typed file variable with a string filename 25 years before generics were added to the mix.

`Assign` is a compiler intrinsic function. That means it lives outside of the Delphi/Pascal syntax space. `Assign` is essentially a type conforming procedure, which can't be represented in the strongly typed Delphi/Pascal language (without modern and complex language extensions such as generic types). It's not typeless, and it's not dynamically typed because the actual parameter type is fully determined at compile time.

You can't take the address of the `Assign` function. Even if you could, because it is amorphous, you won't be able to define a procedure type that accurately represents all of its possible call signatures.

Compiler magic functions exist outside the language to take care of tasks that could not be easily represented in the syntax available at the time. `Assign` is one example. `Writeln`() is another.

Comment: But _AssignFile and _AssignText are NOT intrinsics, those are global routines in System unit, but still you cannot use them to assign to procedure variable,at least not in XE2 console app. Why?

Comment: I seem to recall all symbols exposed in the System unit that begin with an underscore are not accessible to Delphi code outside the unit. I could be wrong on that, but not this: The compiler maps intrinsic symbols onto system unit implementations based on the context in which the intrinsic is used. Also, historically, many of the intrinsic implementations in the system unit do not have formal parameter lists. They receive arguments via registers defined by the compiler outside of the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Assign` is an [intrinsic](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines) function. The [official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Assign) of it is completely hopeless. It says:

```
function Assign(var F: File; FileName: String; [CodePage: Word]): Integer; overload;
function Assign(var F: File; FileName: String; [CodePage: Word]): Integer; overload;
function Assign(var F: File; FileName: String; [CodePage: Word]): Integer; overload;
```

I can only guess as to why the documentation generator cannot cope with this function. But the three identical overloads are clearly bogus. And it's not a function, rather it is a procedure.

No matter. Because it is an intrinsic, you cannot assign it to a function pointer. The solution is to wrap it up in a function of your own.

```
procedure MyAssign(var F: File; const FileName: string);
begin
  Result := System.Assign(F, FileName);
end;
```

You can then assign that function to a variable or constant of procedural type.

```
const
  AssignProc: procedure(var F: File; const FileName: string) = MyAssign;
```

The other variant of `Assign` takes a third parameter that specifies the code page, passed as a `Word`. You can only call that function if the first argument to `Assign` is a `TextFile`.

So, intrinsics are really a law unto themselves.

Note that the documentation does state that `Assign` should no longer be used. Instead you should use `AssignFile`. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AssignFile) is no better there mind you!

Comment: Documentation is very misleading, I tried 3 compiler versions and neither allowed to invoke `Assign` as `function`.

Comment: @user539484 Yes the documentation is alarmingly poor here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it seems they just destroyed their documentation, and while i can understand some random converter bug could cause this, i cannot understand why they cannot just revert MediaWiki history! How would you liek this for exampel: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TComboBox_Properties (same in XE3 doc) - the properties are in HTML sources, but they are intentionally hidden

Comment: @DavidHeffernan while we both agree on wrapper functions, i guess we'd both agree that this would be unpleasant work-around. And that makes me wonder, _AssignFile and _AssignText are NOT intrinsics, but still you cannot use them to assign to procedure variable,at least not in XE2 console app. Why???

Comment: @Arioch'The The special compiler magic around the System unit appears to suppress that symbol to Pascal code. I think you can still reach it with asm.

Answer (score 0):

If to open System.pas file and read it, in XE2 you have those internal procedures:

```
function _AssignFile(var t: TFileRec; const s: PChar): Integer;
function _AssignText(var t: TTextRec; const s: PChar; const CP: word): Integer;
```

And i don't think you have any global stable procedure w/o underscore in names - those listed are Delphi compiler internals, like invisible procedures, that are covertly called when you declare string or dynarray variable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function

Like a lot of procedures like `_Write0LString` which are implementing usual WriteLn calls.

So you would have to make a wrapper function that would call `AssignFile` and put reference to your wrapper into your variable instead;

*However you did not put tag with your Delphi version, and different vesions may have different declarations for intrinsics. So look into sources of your particular Delphi.*

*Also, why would you need it ? I remember i did such a thing in `TurboPascal 5.5` to make string-based file - make `WriteLn` act like C `sprintf`. But why would you need it in modern Delphi, when you can use `TStream` instead?*

Comment: no. i lost it far ago. And it's main value was reverse-engineering data types like `File` and `Text` that are officially published now (and changed since those years significantly) http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.TFileRec http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.TTextRec